# How do you convert ZipFile object in to binary in python?

Tags: python

Let say I create zipfile object like so:

```
with ZipFile(StringIO(), mode='w', compression=ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
            zf.writestr('data.json', 'data_json')
            zf.writestr('document.docx', "Some document")
            
            zf.to_bytes() # there is no such method
```

Can I convert `zf` in to bytes?

**Note**: I'm saying to get a bytes of zipfile it self, not the content files of inside zip archive?

I also prefer to do it in memory without dumping to disk.

Need it to test mocked request that I get from `requests.get` when downloading a zip file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data is stored to the StringIO object, which you didn't save a reference to. You should have saved a reference. (Also, unless you're on Python 2, you need a BytesIO, not a StringIO.)

```
memfile = io.BytesIO()
with ZipFile(memfile, mode='w', compression=ZIP_DEFLATED) as zf:
    ...
data = memfile.getvalue()
```

Note that it's important to call `getvalue` *outside* the `with` block (or after the `close`, if you want to handle closing the ZipFile object manually). Otherwise, your output will be corrupt, missing final records that are written when the ZipFile is closed.